# Spring JPA with Eclipselink save operation does not persist

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink

I've been trying for some couple of days now I just can't seem to figure out why my Eclipselink persistence unit does not perform write operations on my DB. We used to be running OpenJPA and everything was working fine, but with the new EclipseLink config, only thing entities are capable of doing is read data. Write operations do not occur. I'm hoping someone with a better understanding of this can help me out. Maybe I'm missing something.

This is my persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="EclipseLink-PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <shared-cache-mode>ALL</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
        <!--
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database"/>    

        <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.MySQLPlatform" />

        Optimization - avoid auto flush cost on query execution -->
        <!-- property name="eclipselink.batch.size" value="100"/-->
        <property name="javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-persist" value=""/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-update" value="none"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.close-on-commit" value="true"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.flush-mode" value="commit"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL"/>            
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="ALL"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.thread" value="true"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="JDBC"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

My infrastructure.xml with configs for transactionManager

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Necessary to get the entity manager injected into the factory bean -->
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<!-- Define EclipseLink JPA Vendor Adapter -->
<bean id="eclipseLinkAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    depends-on="tenantDatabaseUpgradeService">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="routingDataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="EclipseLink-PU" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.MySQLPlatform"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <!--
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">

        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />

        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatLoadTimeWeaver" />

    </property>-->
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<!-- Create instance of transaction template for programmatic transaction manipulation -->
<bean id="txTemplate" class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
</bean>
```

Here I have a sample entity I want to persist

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "m_office", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "name" }, name = "name_org"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "external_id" }, name = "externalid_org") })
public class Office extends AbstractPersistableCustom implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private List<Office> children = new LinkedList<>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Office parent;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "hierarchy", nullable = true, length = 50)
    private String hierarchy;

    @Column(name = "opening_date", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date openingDate;

    @Column(name = "external_id", length = 100)
    private String externalId;

    public static Office headOffice(final String name, final LocalDate openingDate, final String externalId) {
        return new Office(null, name, openingDate, externalId);
    }

    public static Office fromJson(final Office parentOffice, final JsonCommand command) {

        final String name = command.stringValueOfParameterNamed("name");
        final LocalDate openingDate = command.localDateValueOfParameterNamed("openingDate");
        final String externalId = command.stringValueOfParameterNamed("externalId");
        return new Office(parentOffice, name, openingDate, externalId);
    }

    protected Office() {
        this.openingDate = null;
        this.parent = null;
        this.name = null;
        this.externalId = null;
    }

    private Office(final Office parent, final String name, final LocalDate openingDate, final String externalId) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.openingDate = openingDate.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().toDate();
        if (parent != null) {
            this.parent.addChild(this);
        }

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(name)) {
            this.name = name.trim();
        } else {
            this.name = null;
        }
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(externalId)) {
            this.externalId = externalId.trim();
        } else {
            this.externalId = null;
        }
    }

    private void addChild(final Office office) {
        this.children.add(office);
    }

    public Map<String, Object> update(final JsonCommand command) {

        final Map<String, Object> actualChanges = new LinkedHashMap<>(7);

        final String dateFormatAsInput = command.dateFormat();
        final String localeAsInput = command.locale();

        final String parentIdParamName = "parentId";

        if (command.parameterExists(parentIdParamName) && this.parent == null) { throw new RootOfficeParentCannotBeUpdated(); }

        if (this.parent != null && command.isChangeInLongParameterNamed(parentIdParamName, this.parent.getId())) {
            final Long newValue = command.longValueOfParameterNamed(parentIdParamName);
            actualChanges.put(parentIdParamName, newValue);
        }

        final String openingDateParamName = "openingDate";
        if (command.isChangeInLocalDateParameterNamed(openingDateParamName, getOpeningLocalDate())) {
            final String valueAsInput = command.stringValueOfParameterNamed(openingDateParamName);
            actualChanges.put(openingDateParamName, valueAsInput);
            actualChanges.put("dateFormat", dateFormatAsInput);
            actualChanges.put("locale", localeAsInput);

            final LocalDate newValue = command.localDateValueOfParameterNamed(openingDateParamName);
            this.openingDate = newValue.toDate();
        }

        final String nameParamName = "name";
        if (command.isChangeInStringParameterNamed(nameParamName, this.name)) {
            final String newValue = command.stringValueOfParameterNamed(nameParamName);
            actualChanges.put(nameParamName, newValue);
            this.name = newValue;
        }

        final String externalIdParamName = "externalId";
        if (command.isChangeInStringParameterNamed(externalIdParamName, this.externalId)) {
            final String newValue = command.stringValueOfParameterNamed(externalIdParamName);
            actualChanges.put(externalIdParamName, newValue);
            this.externalId = StringUtils.defaultIfEmpty(newValue, null);
        }

        return actualChanges;
    }

    public boolean isOpeningDateBefore(final LocalDate baseDate) {
        return getOpeningLocalDate().isBefore(baseDate);
    }

    public boolean isOpeningDateAfter(final LocalDate activationLocalDate) {
        return getOpeningLocalDate().isAfter(activationLocalDate);
    }

    public LocalDate getOpeningLocalDate() {
        LocalDate openingLocalDate = null;
        if (this.openingDate != null) {
            openingLocalDate = LocalDate.fromDateFields(this.openingDate);
        }
        return openingLocalDate;
    }

    public void update(final Office newParent) {

        if (this.parent == null) { throw new RootOfficeParentCannotBeUpdated(); }

        if (identifiedBy(newParent.getId())) { throw new CannotUpdateOfficeWithParentOfficeSameAsSelf(getId(), newParent.getId()); }

        this.parent = newParent;
        generateHierarchy();
    }

    public boolean identifiedBy(final Long id) {
        return getId().equals(id);
    }

    public void generateHierarchy() {

        if (this.parent != null) {
            this.hierarchy = this.parent.hierarchyOf(getId());
        } else {
            this.hierarchy = ".";
        }
    }

    private String hierarchyOf(final Long id) {
        return this.hierarchy + id.toString() + ".";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getHierarchy() {
        return this.hierarchy;
    }

    public Office getParent() {
        return this.parent;
    }

    public boolean hasParentOf(final Office office) {
        boolean isParent = false;
        if (this.parent != null) {
            isParent = this.parent.equals(office);
        }
        return isParent;
    }

    public boolean doesNotHaveAnOfficeInHierarchyWithId(final Long officeId) {
        return !hasAnOfficeInHierarchyWithId(officeId);
    }

    private boolean hasAnOfficeInHierarchyWithId(final Long officeId) {

        boolean match = false;

        if (identifiedBy(officeId)) {
            match = true;
        }

        if (!match) {
            for (final Office child : this.children) {
                final boolean result = child.hasAnOfficeInHierarchyWithId(officeId);

                if (result) {
                    match = result;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return match;
    }

    public void loadLazyCollections() {
        this.children.size() ;
    }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using saveAndFlush where appropriate did the trick for me.